# Is it possible to detect external sound continuously in android?

Tags: android, audio, service, alarm

In one of my app I have to detect external sound even app is in background. I have a question on it.

Is it possible to detect external sound continuously even app is in background mode or closed ? If so then will it affect on device battery ?

If it is not possible then is there any alternate way to achieve this ?

Plz let me know about this .

Thanks,

Comment: You can create a service with audio recording example code. Yes it will drain your battery if it is running continuously in background. Even when there is no memory then OS may kill it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response

Comment: @Vigbyor : If we use Watchdog.java class to retrive memory usage and put a condition,if memory usage is greater than 70% then we will run service in foreground, other wise runs in background. do you think that this will work?

Comment: sorry I havent idea how to run service in foreground.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on something like this, and I have used a class that extends service http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html.

As people mentioned above if it is running continuously you may get the android ANR kill wait option. There are two ways I worked around this.

1. make sure that your service is not running on the main ui thread, either using Async or just threading it yourself. Beyond that try to get it to do as little work as you can to avoid that ANR.
2. I limited the amount of time each service lasts. ie, the service listens for a few seconds, runs analysis, saves it, and if conditions are met , creates a new service before calling stopSelf(). This can be a bit hacky, but it can also work depending on what you actually doing with the audio.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I might have misunderstood you

Here's a snippet I use to see if audiofocus changes in conjunction with my MediaPlayer in a Service. You won't know what is playing but you will know if something external is requesting audio:

```
    OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        //Manage audiofocus changes

        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT
                && mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying())
                pausePlaying();
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN
                && mp != null) {
            if (!mp.isPlaying())
                pausePlaying();
        } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS
                && mp != null) {
            am.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener);

            if (mp.isPlaying())
                pausePlaying();
            Log.d("FOCUS", "Focus Changed AUDIOLOSS ");
        }
    }
};
```